# Deploy war to JBOSS

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss

I tried to deploy a Vaadin hello world application in **JBOSS**. The application is as simple as it can be. 
My development environment is eclipse for java EE + **tomcat**

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error configuring property: includeWebInfInClasspath for WarClassLoaderDeployer
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ConfigureAction.dispatchSetProperty(ConfigureAction.java:112)
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ConfigureAction.setAttributes(ConfigureAction.java:85)
    (...)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such property includeWebInfInClasspath for bean org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.WarClassLoaderDeployer available [java2ClassLoadingCompliance, parentFirst, requiredInputs, filteredPackages, allInputs, deploymentRegistry, class, stage, wantComponents, componentsOnly, input, inputs, relativeOrder, output, useUnitName, outputs, topLevelOnly]
```

I have tried to google this error with no success.

Does anyone have any clues?
Is it a web server configuration or my *.war is missing something?

**EDIT:**

This error occur when I start the server after placing my *.war in the folder.
My JBOSS version is 5

Comment: Which version of JBoss? In JBoss 7.1 AS it should be possible to simply place the .war file in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments and then start the server. It should deploy automatically. Does the error above occur when you start JBoss?

Comment: Yes, this error occur when I start the server after placing my *.war in the folder. My JBOSS version is 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you're using an old **JBoss 5**.

The WarClassLoaderDeployer is configured in the file server/default/deployers/jbossweb.deployer/META-INF/war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml. (The 'default' directory should be changed to whatever you passed as -c parameter) Open the file, find the WarClassLoaderDeployer bean and drop the line defining the property with name includeWebInfInClasspath.

Comment: So, In resume: I need to change the web server configuration, not the *.war, correct?

Comment: Additional info: Just put  <property name="includeWebInfInClasspath">true</property> in https://github.com/mp911de/JBoss-Development-Deployer/blob/master/examples/jboss-5.1-war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml class WarClassLoaderDeployer

Comment: Yes, it's an app sever configuration. Nothing to do in your war.